# If $T$ is invertible and $S$ is an isometry, is $TST^{-1}$ an isometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, isometry

I've tried finding a counterexample, but it's hard for me to identify lots of examples where $S$ is an isometry (e.g. in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $S(x,y)=(-y,x)$).  So I haven't found a counterexample.  On the other hand, I haven't been able to prove it either.  Just looking for a hint, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Counterexample:** (using your $S$)
$$
S = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}, 
\quad T = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&1} \implies\\
TST^{-1} = \pmatrix{0&-2\\1/2 & 0}
$$

Comment: As a more general hint for example-hunting, note that every rotation and every reflection is an isometry.

Comment: Since being an isometry is independent of basis, changing basis shouldn't matter, right? (This is what C. Reimann's answer is saying.) Certainly this example establishes that the conjugate of an orthonormal matrix isn't necessarily orthonormal, but I think what's going on in general is that the metric gets reexpressed too (so the matrix won't look orthonormal.) This has been what's running through my head for the last several minutes, and I've been trying to figure out what the problem is...

Comment: @rschwieb changes in basis matter because (in the context of undergrad linear algebra) length is described *relative to a basis* as emerging from the dot-product.  As such, the linear isometries are precisely those which preserve dot products (orthogonal/unitary transformations) and the only changes of basis that preserve isometries are those that are (up to multiplication by a non-zero constant) themselves orthogonal/unitary changes of basis.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't preserve the dot product, but it doesn't seem like the best interpretation to me. At least, it seems counterproductive to geometric intuition. Two people choosing different bases for a vector space should not affect their agreement that a particular transformation preserves distances.

Comment: @rschwieb but the way we determine distances (via the $2$-norm, at any rate) implicitly assumes (at least) that the basis elements are orthogonal to each other, which allows us to apply the "Pythagorean theorem".

Comment: Like I said earlier: if we're pretending the dot product is the only metric that exists, then I agree with you, so I don't have anything to say. The conjugate of an orthonormal matrix will not always be orthonormal, and we're on the same page.

Comment: If we're bringing other metrics into this, though, then it's very onusual for any linear transformation to preserve distances. Even rotations change distances under arbitrary $p$-norms. Ultimately, all metrics on $\Bbb R^n$ are defined relative to some basis, and from that perspective a change of basis is a substantial change

Comment: It's just a viewpoint issue. I'm calling something "the same metric in a different basis" and you're calling the same thing "a different metric." I think they're both valid, depending on which one you think fits the question best. I know where you're coming from, but I'm just reluctant to adopt the other position. I don't think I can provide anything more productive. Regards

Comment: @rschwieb sorry if I've been beating a dead horse, but I find this to be an interesting conversation.  I suppose the hard thing here is to say why does it *feel* as though distances should *not* depend on bases. Regards back at you.

Comment: No worries: this is good food for thought and very stimulating. I think your middle statement is exactly what I'm feeling. Maybe we will eventually figure out one of us has fallen for a complex cognitive lapse. (Could be me, of course! :P)

Answer (score 1):

The change of basis doesn't preserve the metric so there is no reason for $TST^{-1}$ to be an isometry. $TST^{-1}$ is an isometry for the metric $d \circ (T^{-1},T^{-1})$ where $d$ is the classical metric.

In general, $TST^{-1}$ is an isometry iff $T$ is a scalar mutiple of an isometry, or equivalently, iff $T$ preserves the equality of distances. (in the case when $T$ is linear)

Answer (score 0):

To me it is the same linear map. It's just a change of the representation base for the endomorphism. So according to the original base it is still the orthogonal or unitary endomorphism.

For the definition of an isometry by a matrix the rows/cols have to be orthonormal or more general a endomorphism is orthogonal or unitary if, and only if its matrix representation with respect to a orthonormal base is a orthogonal or unitary matrix.

Comment: This has been what's running through my head too.

Comment: the scalar product changes to the matrix with diagonal 1/4, 1.
Then it is still an isometry.

Comment: Hopefully users ponder both solutions carefully. I'm pretty sure the downvote was somewhat carelessly cast.

Comment: It is not the same linear map unless we explicitly specify that it is a matrix representing the same mapping in a new basis. Otherwise  if no change of basis has been specified or implied, then it is a new composite mapping, that in general does does not preserve isometries.  Just my feeling :)

Comment: @rschwieb I cast the downvote. It was not carelessly cast. I think this answer is phrased incongruously enough that I think it will confuse beginners more than anything. "To me it is the same linear map.": well, it simply isn't the same linear map. Sure, you can choose to interpret the new matrix as the representation of the original linear map in a different basis -- but it's still a different matrix, and that matrix simply isn't orthogonal. The orthogonality of a map depends on the scalar product, but the orthogonality of a matrix is a "yes/no" question with no further data needed.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I don't see anyone asking about the orthogonality of a matrix anywhere... If they had, I'd be on the same page as you.

Comment: @rschwieb What do you think "isometry" means? And regardless: if I have an isometry $f$ on some vector space equipped with a scalar product, and a random automorphism $g$ of that vector space, then $gfg^{-1}$ isn't necessarily an isometry. You can decide that every time you conjugate a linear map by an automorphism you conjugate the scalar product too, but that's a weird convention.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi A linear map preserving a particular bilinear form. Not "a linear map preserving the dot product" necessarily. Of course, chaining yourself to an orthonormal basis changes things.

Comment: @rschwieb I thought I was fast enough, but I expanded my comment in the meantime, sorry. "chaining yourself to an orthonormal basis changes things": that's exactly what considering linear maps as matrices is doing... Chaining yourself to a basis.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I don't think it's weird at all. If I hand you a vector space, a bilinear form, and a transformation all in the abstract, and you pick some random basis and write everything in terms of that basis, and I do the same with some completely different random basis, I think we ought to agree at all times whether or not the transformation preserves the form. At any rate, I could have misjudged the OP's intention, and I certainly understand where you're coming from. I don't think there is much productive left to say.

Comment: The tags include linear algebra but the Q does not state that S and T are necessarily linear.

Comment: @Najibldrissi, I don't wanted to confuse anybody. My intention was to give the Questioner a "hint" as demanded; complementary to your certainly satisfying answer.Matrix representations of linear maps were one of the first things I had to learn as an undergrad and to me it seems not natural to talk about such topics like isometries without knowing what a base of vector space is.

Comment: @Najibldrissi. nonremoveable asked about if its isometric. Thats a property of an endomorphsim not a property of a matrix, unless you define it otherwise of course, but that would actually be the weird thing. This suggests, someone who want to talk about abstract linear algebra, i. e. not about a concrete representation.
A change of base won't change that - thats the reason why we define it as a property of the endomorphism.
Do we transform or looking at an entire different object - thats the question.
The question lacks precision - thats all the magic.